# React.js uncaught Typing error tolowercase() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import SearchBar from './component/SearchBar';
    import UserList from './component/UserList';
    import AddUser from './component/AddUser';





    class App extends React.Component {

        state = {
            users: [

            ],
            searchQuery: ""
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            this.getUsers();
         }

         async getUsers() {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3004/users");
            //console.log(response);
            this.setState({ users: response.data })
        }



        deleteUser = async (user) => {
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:3004/users/${user.id}`)
            const newUserList = this.state.users.filter(
                m => m.id !== user.id
            )


            this.setState(state => ({
                users: newUserList
            }))

        }


        searchUser = (event) => {
           
            this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value })
        }



        addUser = async (user) => {
            await axios.post(`http://localhost:3004/users/`, user)

            this.setState(state => ({
                users:state.users.concat([user])
            }))
            this.getUsers();
        }

        render() {

            let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter(
                (user) => {
                    return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                }
            ).sort( (a, b) => {
                return a.id < b.id ? 1 : a.id > b.id ? -1 : 0;
            });

            return (
                <Router>

                    <div className="container">
                        <Switch>  
                            <Route path="/" exact render={() => (

                            <React.Fragment>

                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <SearchBar searchUserProp={this.searchUser} />

                                        <UserList
                                            users={filteredUsers}
                                            deleteUserProp={this.deleteUser}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </React.Fragment>

                        )} > </Route>

                            <Route path="/add" render={({history}) => (
                            
                            
                            <AddUser 
                            onAddUser = {(user) => {this.addUser(user)
                            history.push("/")}}
                            />)} /> 
                            
                            </Switch>

                    </div>

                </Router>
            )

        }

    }

    export default App;
```

It was working without problem until I added edit component. I was learning and I don't know where did I mistake. It says tolowercase() function but when I totally delete them, empty screen comes. I guess there is no relation about it. I took this error once but I solved now it is too different now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user array is empty, then user.name will be undefined, and user.name.toLowerCase() will throw an error.

So you can do something like this, by adding in the ? question marks.

```
user?.name?.toLowerCase()?.indexOf(this.state.searchQuery?.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

Final codes can be something like this

```
let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter(
            (user) => user?.name?.toLowerCase()?.indexOf(this.state.searchQuery?.toLowerCase()) !== -1 )

filteredUsers = filteredUsers.length > 1 ? filteredUsers.sort( (a, b) => {
            return a.id < b.id ? 1 : a.id > b.id ? -1 : 0;
        }) : filteredUsers //only sort if more than 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked the json file and saw it corrupted. I drove mad cuz I coulndn't find any relation about tolowercase() function. Now, I see.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is wrapping all code that uses the `user` object with a simple `if` statement or `ternary` operator. The reason you would want to do this is, if the `user` object starts without default values, it is considered an empty object, so using `user.name` would be undefined, which you may have noticed since you are getting an error.

Dive a bit deeper into React, and you will notice that `componentDidMount` runs after the component has mounted to the `DOM` (you are fetching data at the right spot!!). This means that all the code in the `render` function will run before you populate the `user` object, which is the reason for the error you are getting. So, in order to fix this problem, you can do as follows:

```
// Start of the ternary operator.
// If the user object is not empty, the code after the '?' and before the ':' will
// be executed. If the object is empty, then 'null' will be returned causing you 
// to not be given an error.
user ? 
 let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter((user) => {
    return ( 
        user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      )}
      ).sort( (a, b) => {
         return a.id < b.id ? 1 : a.id > b.id ? -1 : 0;
 })
: null
// You can replace null with any value that you like, or you can keep it null.
```

So, to wrap this answer up, if you want to use data that you know may not always be defined, wrap where you use the data with a ternary operator or `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchBar from './component/SearchBar';
import UserList from './component/UserList';
import AddUser from './component/AddUser';
import EditUser from './component/EditUser';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        users: [],
        searchQuery: ""
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovies();
    }

    async getMovies() {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3004/users");
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
    }

    deleteUser = async (user) => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:3004/users/${user.id}`)
        const newUserList = this.state.users.filter(
            m => m.id !== user.id
        )
        this.setState(state => ({
            users: newUserList
        }))
    }

    searchUser = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value })
    }

    addUser = async (user) => {
        await axios.post(`http://localhost:3004/users/`, user)
        this.setState(state => ({
            users: state.users.concat([user])
        }))
        this.getMovies();
    }

    editUser = async (id, updatedUser) => {
        await axios.put(`http://localhost:3004/users/${id}`, updatedUser)
        this.setState(state => ({
            users: state.users.concat([updatedUser])
        }))
        this.getMovies();
    }

    render() {

        let filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter(
            (user) => {
                return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            }
        ).sort((a, b) => {
            return a.id < b.id ? 1 : a.id > b.id ? -1 : 0;
        });

        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="container">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <SearchBar searchUserProp={this.searchUser} />
                                    <UserList
                                        users={filteredUsers}
                                        deleteUserProp={this.deleteUser}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/add" render={({ history }) => (
                            <AddUser onAddUser={(user) => {
                                this.addUser(user)
                                history.push("/")
                            }} />
                        )} />
                        <Route path="/edit/:id" exact render={(props) => (
                            <EditUser
                                {...props}
                                onEditUser={(id, user) => {
                                    this.editUser(id, user)
                                }
                                }
                            />
                        )} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>

            </Router>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

I solved the problem. The problem was, when I submit empty add form, the json file corrupted. I edited the json file plus I improved the codes to get the data for being accurate simultaneously by adding getdata function in componentdidmount.